# How can I retrieve mouse cursor images on ubuntu in C or C++

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working on an application in which the user can create custom tools and would like the user to be able to choose a mouse cursor (from a pre-defined list) that's active while the tool is being used.
This is a C++ application that uses Qt and only needs to run on Ubuntu.
Is there a way to retrieve those cursor images programmatically?

I was able to retrieve the images of most cursors using QCursor::pixmap(), but there are some cursors for which QCursor returns an empty pixmap (Qt::ArrowCursor aka left_ptr, Qt::CrossCursor aka cross, Qt::OpenHandCursor aka openhand, Qt::ClosedHandCursor aka closedhand, Qt::SizeVerCursor aka size_ver and Qt::SizeHorCursor aka size_hor).

Comment: On Linux, the mouse-cursor is drawn by an X-cursor theme. My original thought would be to grab the mouse-cursor them name from a config file (not sure on Ubuntu, but likely desktop or WM specific, Gtk, Qt, etc..). Then just load the cursor file from from the cursor-theme folder in `/usr/share/icons/your-theme-name` (or under `~/.local/share/...` if you loaded the cursor theme as user. Otherwise, you are going to have to get the cursor position and grab a rectangle around it and then do some type of tracing to identify the cursor in that rectangle (which can be right or left oriented)

Comment: Additionally, not all X-cursor themes have images for each cursor. Many use the same image to fill multiple roles. This is configured in the theme's directory where cursor names may be *soft-linked* to another image.